# Full screen image in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

How do you make an `<Image>` fill the entire `UIWindow` sized area in React Native? If I were using Autolayout I would set a constraint on each edge, but flux is very different paradigm and I'm not a web guy. Without setting a manual width/height on my `<Image>` nothing shows up, but how do I dynamically tell the style to be the same as the width and heigh of its parent element, or at the very least the window?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use [flexbox](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#proptypes). Here's a full example:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image
} = React;

var TestCmp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/400/sports/5/'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RCTTest', () => TestCmp);
```

Notice that you need a container to allow you to define the flex of items within it. The key here is `alignItems: 'stretch'` to make the contents of imageContainer fill the available space.

[image: iOS Simulator Screenshot]

Comment: Perfect. This is pretty much what I had, only I was using `"center"` instead of `"stretch"`. Lots of little things like that I'll have to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I guess you'd have had to set a pixel width to get it to appear with "center". Remember that flexbox in React Native is an implementation of the flexbox spec so you should be able to use the docs and guides for that to help get to grips with it. Here's a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm using a listview to display images, might the listview cause an issue with this?

Comment: Possibly. Like I said in my answer, the containing styles have an effect too. Might be worth opening a new question as it sounds slightly different, though the only thing I'd say is that this could technically be more of a flexbox question than React Native.

Comment: Is there any way to have the image "fit" inside the full screen?  This only seems to work if I specify a width and height of the image.  If the image is larger than the screen then you get a centered clipped version where I'd rather have it fit inside the screen.  I was trying to see if this was possible manually even but I can't see how to get the available screen size (or parent view size) to be able to manually resize the image to.

Comment: i have basically copy pasted your code and got `You are trying to render the global image variable as a react variable. You probably forgot to require image. ` edit : my bad,  forgot to add `Image` to require `var {
  Image
} = React;`

Comment: still not working,  the screen is empty.. what am I missing here?

Comment: @MikeDriver resizeMode: contain - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode

Comment: @ColinRamsay  I have the same issue but your suggested fix here didn't work for that, could you please have a look at it? thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775797/the-top-part-of-the-image-that-i-loaded-for-the-card-is-missing

Answer (score 3):

if support Android and iOS you can use this code ,
you need hide Toolbar and StatusBar

**StatusBar hiden**

```
return (
        <View style={styles.root_layout}>
            <StatusBar hidden={true} />
            ...
        </View>
    )
```

**ToolBar hiden**

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```