# the top part of the image that i loaded for the Card is missing

Tags: react-native

I am using [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/card/). The [image](http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-04.jpg) that I upload for my `Card` is not displayed fully, The 1/3 top part of the image is missing. I tried to give `flex:1` to the Card style but didn't work. Below is my original code:

```
<Card        
        image={require('./src/images/MaggieSimpson.png')}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          No more cards to show :)
        </Text>
        <Button
          icon={{ name: 'code' }}
          backgroundColor='#03A9F4'
          bottonStyle={{ borderRadius: 10, margin: 10 }}
          title='add more cards'
        />
</Card>
```

what should I  add to it to show the whole image?

below is the image that get on by device:

[image]
and this the image that it should be :

http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/paul0v2/unsplash/unsplash-04.jpg

if i do `imageStyle={{ height: 300}}` it shows the whole image, but i want it to be flexible and stretch as much the picture is, 
P.S. i used

```
imageContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1
  }
```

and it didn't work

Comment: Can you show your output image screenshot ?

Comment: @Dane  what is that o/p?

Comment: Try using the `imageStyle` and `imageWrapper` `props`, both mentioned in the link you shared.

Comment: @Dane  I tried `flex: 1` but didn't work, what style should I use to make the whole image displayed? something related to the image size not just changing the hight

Comment: either share an image of your output or some code so that people can help you

Comment: @Dane   i added the image that i get from the device and the original one

Comment: Try placing the image using CSS property `background-image` and set `background-size: cover`

Comment: @Dane  could you add more info and post it as an answer, thanks